# Integrate mat-table with AngularFirestore With Sorting and Searching

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire, angular-material2

I'm looking to do the exact same thing as answered here:

[Integrate mat-table with AngularFirestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798870/integrate-mat-table-with-angularfirestore)

But I would like to enable sorting and filtering for the Mat-Table, though. Is it simple or do I have to implement a complex solution like the one below?

[Angular Material 2 Data Table Connect to AngularFire2 or Firebase Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336706/angular-material-2-data-table-connect-to-angularfire2-or-firebase-service)